multi query 5 tables with only 1 ID, join query to get result from the 5 table
About my tables, I am creating a script for a game I like to play, if people has XYZ statement assigned to their account. Its based on 4 tables. 1 table with the past games saved with a match ID, then the next table holds match ID to player ID relation, table 3 then hold the player ID with the in-game ID whereas the last table holds info about what statement is assigned to them.
There can be up 15 players in 1 match, hence the relation tables, some players are seen more than once in different matches.
So the tables look like this: games (match ID) -> match to player (match ID to player ID) -> players (Player ID to In-game ID) -> player Info (In-game ID -> info needed to query)
So when the script is queried, I have the match owner UID which is saved with the match data in the first table with match information, it would return all the match IDs based on that owner ID, so all the match IDs then checks the next table to get all the unique player IDs, with that list then query next table to get a list of all those in-game IDs, with that list then query the last table to get each players in-game assignments.
I cant change the way the tables are, since all other scripts are depending on those.
I have tried some join statements, but none gotten what I needed and none even half what I wanted, but I do think its the usage of joins that will get me to where I need to be.

I am trying to get a list from the last table on the picture based on the ID from the first table. I know I need to use joins, however I am not sure how to in what order, some guideline is needed as to how I organize the joins to get the data I need.
SELECT b.*
FROM banInfo AS b
JOIN players AS p ON b.game_id=p.game_id
JOIN player2match AS pm ON pm.pid=p.id
JOIN matches AS m ON m.id=pm.mid
JOIN users AS u ON u.id=m.uid
WHERE u.id = 1 AND b.comBan = 1 OR b.playerBan > 0 OR b.nGameBan > 0

This is the query I have so far, its semi working since it does return a list of the needed info, but there is way more than there should be, so somehow its selecting something it shouldn't, the thing is I dont know how many total it should return, that's one of the things I am gonna need the query for, to get a total count of it. But I do know it returns to many, as there is a total of 1355 banned players from the database in total, but this query returns 2254 rows, so somehow selected why more than it should.
I was looking at SQL statement is ignoring where parameter, however it does mot fully answer my answer, as mine is with joins and more, the question here was combined with join.
I did manage the fix it myself with help from the comments in the question, so please reopen the question, so I can answer the question and make the guy who helped me marked as solution.
Thanks!

Do you take into account that the precedence of AND operator is higher than those of OR operator?

@Akina I believe so yes, the u.id has to match and be there for the user ID, but it can either be one of the ban versions or am I missing something? :)

There is 1,510 rows if either of the OR is 1 or above if user ID is not taken into account, but the query returns 2423 rows, so it should return way less rows, way under the 1.5k rows. Not sure how many it should return, but maybe max 100 to 200

Try to add max. amount of parenthesis into your WHERE, exclude any ambiguity in operators execution order. For example, .. WHERE (u.id = 1) AND (((b.comBan = 1) OR (b.playerBan > 0)) OR (b.nGameBan > 0))

@Akina That returned 176 rows, seems way more correct, I will have to test the query a bit more later today when I got a bit more time to test more IDs and queries, but if its correct which I think it is, I will accept it as the correct answer, thank you very much so far!

Sorry @Akina, they closed the question, so cant mark your answer as the solution. But it did work and is correct. Very grateful for your help!
